# React Native disable navigation push animation

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Considering a simple example in React Native that uses React Navigation to go to a different screen, how can I disable the transition animation?

```
<Button
  title="Go to Details... again"
  onPress={() => navigation.push('Details')}
/>
```

[See the example on Snack](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=push&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative-stack%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%405.0.4%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%401.5.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%401.4.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%400.6.0%2Creact-native-screens%402.0.0-alpha.12&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fmultiple-push.js)

Answer (score 0):

set animationEnabled to false

```
screen: YourScreenName,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      animationEnabled: false,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting "animationEnabled: false"?

check out the docs for it here:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#animationenabled